# Access Violation on MASM (Unhandled exception at 0x00000002 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000002.)

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

So, I'm accessing somewhere wrong, but I just can't figure it out. I know my code is super bad, so feel free to fix it or point out the mistakes. However, what I really want to know is how to fix this (title) particular error.
I only can understand MASM.
Thank you.

Below is my code in MASM.

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .data
      v1 dword 2
      v2 dword 2
      s1 byte "Please enter a number:",0
      s3 byte "|       The value will be recognized as non signed      |",0Ah, 0
      s4 byte "|By definition of Prime Number, number can't be negative|",0Ah, 0

 .code

 main proc
      mov edx, offset s4
      call writestring
      mov edx, offset s3
      call writestring
      mov edx, offset s1
      call writestring
      call readdec
      mov ecx, eax
      dec ecx
      dec ecx
      L1:
           push ecx
           push v2
           mov eax, v1
           push eax
           xor edx, edx
           mov ebx, 2
           div ebx
           mov ecx, eax
           call isPrime
           pop v2
           pop ecx
           inc v1
           cmp edx, 0
           JE L4
           LOOP L1

      L4:
           call writedec
           dec ecx
           JMP L1

      exit
 main endp

 isPrime proc
      L2:
           pop eax
           push eax
           xor edx, edx
           div v2
           cmp edx, 0
           JE L3
           inc v2
           LOOP L2

           pop eax
           mov edx, 0
           ret

      L3:
           pop eax
           mov edx, 1
           ret  <----------- ERROR OCCURS HERE.

 isPrime endp

 end main
```

Okay, I fixed the problem and now it's working
code is below

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .data
      v1 dword 2
      v2 dword 2
      s1 byte "Please enter a number:",0
      s3 byte "|       The value will be recognized as non signed      |",0Ah, 0
      s4 byte "|By definition of Prime Number, number can't be negative|",0Ah, 0
      s5 byte "No Prime found.", 0Ah, 0
      s6 byte "Primes found until the given number:", 0Ah, 0

 .code

 main proc

           mov edx, offset s4
           call writestring
           mov edx, offset s3
           call writestring
           mov edx, offset s1
           call writestring
           call readdec
           ;if(eax < 2)
           cmp eax, 2
           JB L6
           mov ecx, eax
           dec ecx
           dec ecx
           ;if(ecx < 1)
           cmp ecx, 1
           JB L7
      L1:
           push ecx
           mov eax, v1
           push eax
           xor edx, edx
           div v2
           mov ecx, eax
           pop eax
           mov ebx, v2
           call isPrime
           pop ecx
           inc v1
           ;if (edx == 0)
           cmp edx, 0
           JE L4
           ;if (eax == 2)
           cmp eax, 2
           JE L5
           LOOP L1

           exit

      L4:
           call writedec
           mov al, ' '
           call writechar
           dec ecx
           ;if(ecx > 0)
           cmp ecx, 0
           JA L1
           exit
      L5:
           mov edx, offset s6
           call writestring
           call writedec
           mov al, ' '
           call writechar
           dec ecx
           ;if(ecx > 0)
           cmp ecx, 0
           JA L1
           exit

      L6:
           mov edx, offset s5
           call writestring
           exit
      L7:
           mov edx, offset s6
           call writestring
           call writedec
           mov al, ' '
           call writechar
           exit

 main endp

 COMMENT!
 isPrime recieves eax and ebx. And, it returns edx as boolean, eax as number.
 !
 isPrime proc
      L2:
           push eax
           xor edx, edx
           div ebx
           ;if(edx == 0)
           cmp edx, 0
           JE L3
           inc ebx
           pop eax
           LOOP L2

           xor edx, edx
           ret

      L3:
           pop eax
           mov edx, 1
           ret 

 isPrime endp

 end main
```

Comment: You need to balance your PUSH and POP instructions so that RET can pop off the correct return address.

Comment: so after I call procedure, I just can't push more into stack?

Comment: What the error is generally telling you is you are accessing the number `2` (`0x00000002`) as an address instead of a value. (e.g. you are using the number as a pointer attempting to access the memory address `2` which is well down in the system reserved block of memory) Apparently, the address used by your return is not what you think it is.

Comment: I'm no masm expert and don't know how it handles the function prolog/epilog, but it appears the address for base pointer for the return of `isPrime` to `main` when it completes is not valid. See [**Function prologue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue)

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I fixed error, and I'm debugging it now.